# Issue with file edit in PHP using file_put_contents (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, image, file, croppie

Good afternoon everyone, I have run across a weird issue which I can't put my finger on and I am hoping somebody can help me figure out what is causing this problem.
To provide some context, I allow the user to store an array of images on a product, and after they are stored using laravel-stapler package which is configured in the following way:

```
 public function __construct(array $attributes = [])
{
    parent::__construct($attributes);

    $this->hasAttachedFile('image', [
        'styles' => [
            'thumbnail' => '500x500#',
            'large' => '800x800#'
        ],
        'url' => '/media/image/:id/:style/:filename',
        'default_url' => '/img/category-placeholder-greyscale.jpg',
        'convert_options' => [
            'jpeg_quality' => 60
        ]
    ]);
}
```

The images are saved in three folders: 
../path-to-image/original/file-name 
../path-to-image/thumbnail/file-name 
../path-to-image/large/file-name 

After I save these images I use croppie.js to rotate and edit them. After the user edits and crops them and they submit it the image is sent as a base64 to a controller and the controller is shortened below to only the relevant parts:

```
$imageData = $request->get('imagebase64');

list(, $imageData) = explode(';', $imageData);
list(, $imageData) = explode(',', $imageData);
$imageData = base64_decode($imageData);
// $image is loaded up through dependency injection
$path = public_path('/path' . '/large/' . $image->image_file_name);
$path2 = public_path('/path' . '/original/' . $image->image_file_name);


file_put_contents($path, $imageData);
file_put_contents($path2, $imageData);
```

This works on my local machine just fine, the image is saved in both folders and I get a new cropped and edited image, but on my server this doesn't work, the first **file_put_contents** doesn't work and doesn't store a new image into the **/large** folder but the second file_put_contents works and stores a new image into the **/original** folder. 

I am not sure why does this happen and would appreciate any help you can give me. I also do not think it is due to permissions because I gave the folder for the images the right permission but I can't be certain. The code doesn't crash also it just executes without saving the first image

Comment: Did you check privilages on the directories that fail

Comment: Any error message? Do some silly tests - set another path, replace file_put's, set more file_put's and test which one fail, ...

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yeah I did, the perimissions look good. im not good with linux but could this have something to do with daemons?

Comment: @blackblue none at all, it just silently fails, I tried deleting the file_put that stores into the /original folder, the other one still failed, I also tried using chmod($path, 777) just to see what happens and it actually worked but then crashed right after, so it seems it has something to do with permissions but can't figure out what exactly

Comment: Not necessarily - I can't recall details - had some problem first fails, next without problems - was something about ... timing - let's say variable wasn't ready :) bug was somewhere else above and whole code was parsed as valid

Comment: @blackblue the reason I think it doesn't have anything to do with the code is because it works locally when I do it but it doesn't on production env.

Answer (score 0):

you might have to edit the .htaccess file to give permissions to these files